# Браузер Steam не загружает страницы в Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, steam, httpsurlconnection

Использовал версии Linux Mint 17.3 и 18.3 (Cinnamon оболочка). Установил legacy драйвер nvidia-304, чтобы Steam запускался. Установил сам Steam командой

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Установилось и обновилось все прекрасно. Ошибок не заметил. Даже игра скачалась и установилась (правда, не запускается). Но вот браузер steam в его вкладке Магазин/Store не грузит страницы, идет бесконечная загрузка. В терминале ничего дополнительного по этому поводу не видно. Устал искать в интернете решение. Вроде по умолчанию все порты открыты. Поправьте, если не прав.

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Для работы Steam [как у них написано](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711&l=russian) нужны определенные открытые порты, но я не могу это проверить. Кроме того, в браузере линукса магазин стима открывается. И проблем с роутером тут быть не должно, так как с другого компьютера (Windows) все прекрасно играет.

Помогите разобраться, почему не работает встроенный браузер Steam.

Comment: Кажется, была такая проблема...

Comment: Кажется, меня игнорируют...

Comment: Кажется, никто не знает, как решить...

Comment: А почему nvidia-304? У меня без проблем всё работает на nvidia-390.

Comment: Точно такая же проблема есть у стима под вайном, если не установить corefonts, но нативно никогда такого не видел. Возможно у вас какие-то базовые шрифты не установлены/удалены, хотя без нормальных логов это всё пальцем в небо.